# On click I'm getting error "Argument is not optional"

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried the following code in Excel. It is connecting successfully. I want to get input values from user. To get value from user, I have used `Range.Value("N3")` and `Range.Value("N4")`.

It works fine without getting value in that way. But when I add value on excel sheet and click the button to fetch records,

it gives me the error

> "Argument is not optional"

If someone here can check this?

Here is the code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim mon As String
Dim yea As String

mon = Range.Value("N3")
yea = Range.Value("N4")

' Create a connection object.
Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.
strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"

'Connect to the Pubs database on the local server.
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=(local);INITIAL CATALOG=inFlow;"

'Use an integrated login.
strConn = strConn & " INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"

'Now open the connection.
cnPubs.Open strConn

' Create a recordset object.
Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rsPubs
' Assign the Connection object.
.ActiveConnection = cnPubs
' Extract the required records.
.Open "exec dbo.ReportTotalCompanyMonthlySales ' & yea & ',' & mon&'"

' Copy the records into cell A1 on Sheet1.
Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsPubs

' Tidy up
.Close
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mon = Range("N3").Value
```

instead of

```
mon = Range.Value("N3")
```

Comment: Now, it is working fine. I have another issue, the retrieved data does not have column names. How can I get them as well from SQL?

Comment: @Arslan ud Din Shafiq You need to loop though the fields and add their name manually. See how it's done here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copyfromrecordset-method-excel

Comment: @Arslan ud Din Shafiq if my answer helped you solve the problem please mark it solved and upvot... it will help me earn some badge..